# phantomjs render method and css issue

Tags: css, phantomjs, render

I'm using phantomjs 1.9.7

On my devbox (OSX), the screenshot is perfect.
On prod (CentOS 5.9), it looks like elements of the screenshot don't have css rules applied.
These rules are font-size.
I tried to add a javascript setTimeout before to make the screenshot but it didn't helped.
Any idea ?

Thanks to all !

Comment: Does the page use any web fonts?

Comment: No, but the page that I want to screenshot is web page based on twitter bootstrap and the Helvetica Neue font seems to have issues to render on linux environment. On OSX, it's OK. Finally, I stopped using it and used a more regular font.